Relation between permanent and row sums
I am studying about permanent of the matrix and I stumbled upon some equations that describe the permanent or bound its value using the row sums of the matrix.
For example, Ryser formula states that: Suppose $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. Let $A_k$ be obtained from $A$ by deleting $k$ columns, let $P(A_k)$ be the product of the row-sums of $A_k$, and let $\Sigma_k$ be the sum of the values of $P(A_k)$ over all possible $A_k$. Then, $perm(A) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}\Sigma_k$.
Another example is the upper bound on the permanent by Bregman theorem,
$M(A) := \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}(r (i)!)^{1/r (i)} \geq per (A)$
Can anyone explain me why row sums pop up often in the expressions relating to permanent and an intuition as to how permanent and row sums are connected?
(Sources: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_the_permanent, https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=dan&paperid=37755&option_lang=eng)
